# WebCameraの画像をフックし、PyOpenCVで画像処理をおこないZoomに表示する方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, ffmpeg

WebCameraの画像をフックし、画像処理をおこないZoomに表示したいと思っています。
具体的には、
WebCam → PyOpenCV → ffmpeg → (仮想デバイス) ???

似た資料を探すと、Ubuntuにて、Pythonとv4l2Loopbackを使っている記事を見つけました。
WebCam → PyOpenCV → ffmpeg → (仮想デバイス)v4l2loopback
[TeamsやZoomでカメラ画像を加工する方法 - フレクトのクラウドblog re:newal](https://cloud.flect.co.jp/entry/2020/03/31/162537)

osxでどうすれば実現可能か調べているが、いまいち方法が分からないです。

OBSやGStreamerと行ったソフトが見つかるが、
具体的にffmpegからどのように映像を送るのかが分からず困っています。

ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 方法が違うかもしれませんがこんな記事があるようです。[OBS (macOS) Virtual Camera で遊ぶ](https://qiita.com/tearoom6/items/2747b49e36890b062b46), [ライブ配信アプリOBS Studioに仮想カメラを作り出し、ZoomやGoogle Meetなどに映像を直接配信できるOBSプラグイン「OBS (macOS) Virtual Camera」がリリース。](https://applech2.com/archives/20200520-obs-studio-for-mac-virtual-camera-plugin.html), [Mac版「Zoomアプリ」再び仮想カメラをサポート、Snap Cameraが使えるように](https://www.danshihack.com/2020/05/28/junp/zoom-for-mac-virtual-camera.html)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まさにSnapCameraがやっているような処理を独自でやりたかったのですが。。なかなかハードルが高そうです。